# Regex to allow any charcter EXCEPT backslash

Tags: regex

I am using jQuery Validation Engine plugin. This regex allows only Alpha Numeric, I want to allow any other character except backslash.

```
/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one (escaping the backslash will depend on your langage):

```
/^[^\\]+$/
```

Comment: It is javascript. It worked correctly. I will accept as soon as able.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[^\\]+$/
```

This is a negated character class for the backslash.  You need two of them in the regex literal or it will try to escape the `]`